# RegEx to Match Query String on App Engine Console Log

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use labels within the app engine console to search for url pattern:

```
/path?company_id=1234
```

I am using the label filter:

```
querystring:/(company_id=1234)
```

I get nothing back even though I can see it in the log, can someone explain what I am doing wrong here? I tried it in a RegEx checker and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter you're filtering on is not the only one, you need to use a wildcard, like this

```
querystring:.*company_id=1234.*
```

Also, you don't need to add the `/` or the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Rather, than using the legacy appengine console you're probably better off diving into the cloud console. The log viewer has been much improved: https://console.developers.google.com

The following should just work for you:

```
querystring:company_id=1234
```

Comment: Honorable mention here because you're probably right, this is a good suggestion, I have the accepted to the other answer because it answered my actual question. I will probably try this in the future, thanks for the help!